# should i use the definite article " free from the British rule" or "free from British rule"

Tags: definite-articles

Should I use the definite article as in *the British rule* or can I say:

*The colonies are now independent and free from British rule, and King
George III is now replaced by General George Washington.*

Comment: Generally, in US English, you would NOT use the definite article in the above example.

Comment: Hot Licks is quite right… if you really wanted to throw an article in there, you   could try *free from the rule of Britain* but that's a rather different thing, is it not?

Comment: and why not add 'the King George III' or 'the General GW'? Definite articles are used when you want to be definite I guess

Comment: But, when Lower Slobbovia switches from imperial units to metric units, one could rightfully say it's "free from the British rule".

Comment: Ho, ho, ho and I still believe *imperial* measure comes from Charlemagne and the Holy Roman Empire, not from anything British.

Comment: I can no other answer make but thanks, thanks, and ever thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The definite article isn’t necessary because “British rule” is definite enough as it is. Saying “*the* British Rule” doesn’t make the noun phrase “British rule” any more specific, so you can easily say it without the *the*.